# String still the same after javascript concat

Tags: javascript

I have the below code that for some reason is completely ignoring the concats in the if/else statement:

```
returntext = '' +
             '<div>' +
             '<h4>test ' + profile.id + '">' + profile.name + '</a></h4>' +
             '<div class="message-content">' +
             message.content +
             '</div>'

if (showtrash) {
    toadd = '' + '<span class="pull-right small">' + '<a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-trash trash-message"></i></a> ' + '</span>' + '</div>'
    returntext.concat(toadd);
} else {
    returntext.concat('<span class="pull-right small">' + '</span>' + '</div>');
}
console.log(returntext);
```

However the console log just shows that returntext is equal to the string before the if/else statement.

What is the right way to do what I am trying to achieve?
Thanks

Comment: There is no purpose whatsoever to the `'' +` just after the `=` in either places it occurs in the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to assign the result of the `concat`:

```
returntext = returntext.concat(toadd);
```

The `concat` method creates a new string, and you should assign the result to (another) variable.

Answer (score 4):

you should use:

```
returntext = returntext.concat...
```

in you code.